# React Native, passing function with argument from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have written a code that passes the parent's function to the child. When the function executes a child, the parent element will log to console with the passing argument(which passes from a child).

But I got an error that `handlesubmit` is not a function.

Below is the parent component

```
const Parent=()=>{
 const handlesubmit=(value)=>{console.log(value)}
return (
<Child handlesubmit={handlesubmit} />
)
}
```

Below is the child

```
const Child=(handlesubmit)=>{
return(
<Button  onPress={()=>handlesubmit('hi')} />
)
}
```

Comment: Because handlesubmit is referencing to props which is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop will be passed to the child as an argument: the first parameter to the child is an object containing all props:

```
const Child = ({ handlesubmit }) => {
  return (
    <Button onPress={() => handlesubmit('hi')} />
  );
};
```

Or you could do

```
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <Button onPress={()=> props.handlesubmit('hi')} />
  );
};
```

(it would also be good to use proper indentation when writing code - that will let you identify all `{` `}` blocks at a glance, making the code more readable for everyone *and* reducing potential bugs)

Also, is your `Button` another component, or are you trying to render a `<button>`? If `<button>`, then you'll need to use that capitalization, and use `onClick`, not `onPress` (which doesn't exist):

```
const Child = ({ handlesubmit }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => handlesubmit('hi')} />
  );
};
```

Comment: That's destructuring, extracting the property out of the object into a single variable. It's commonly done in React to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
const Child = ({ handlesubmit }) => {
  return(
    <Button onClick={()=>handlesubmit('hi')} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to desctructure Child props, onPress is not one of an event listener use onClick, or onSubmit instead.

Try to look at this code:

```
const Child = (props) => {
  const { handlesubmit } = props;
  return <Button onClick={handlesubmit('hi')} />;
};
```